Backup a Postgres's schema and upload into s3 using python-aws glue
I am using AWS Glue service to back up specific Postgres schema and upload the file into s3. I know glue may not be ideal service but I need to use that only. Here is the code that I am using which is not working.
def backup_schema(schema):
    try:
        backup_file = "/tmp/backup.sql"
        subprocess.run([
            "pg_dump",
            "-h", host,
            "-p", str(port),
            "-U", user,
            "-d", dbname,
            "-n", schema,
            "-f", backup_file
        ], check=True)
        print('subprocess done')
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
        s3_client.upload_file(backup_file, 'bucket_name', 'postgress-backup/backup.sql')

        print("Backup successful!")

But this one is not working.Gives error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pg_dump': 'pg_dump'
What is the best way to achieve this using python?

Use the absolute path to pg_dump.
